# Correct use of transimpedance amp

Tags: arduino, photodiode, 5v, operational-amplifier

So I realized that it might become a necessity for me to use a transimpedance amplifier for a pulse watch that I intend to make.

Some background:

The pulse watch shoots light at 940 and 660nm at the wrist and picks up the reflected light in a photodiode (https://dk.farnell.com/hamamatsu/s1223/photodiode-pin-to-5/dp/1495587).

Hence why the signal that the photodiode picks up may be diluted and subject to noise, if I don't treat it correctly.
The V_Out signal is supposed to go into my Arduinos analog port from which, I (hopefully) can draw a nice pulse curve.

As I'm not an electrical engineer, the primary part that I'm unsure about is the operational amplifier that I inserted into the circuit. 
I tried to look around for similar applications, but I'm still unsure about the capacitors, and resistors that I've put in there (if the values are correct).

The op-amp I intend to use is this: https://dk.farnell.com/texas-instruments/op07cd/ic-op-amp-low-offset-smd-soic8/dp/9589929?st=OP07

[image]

1. Is this application of the operational amplifier correct, with correct resistor and capacitor values, i.e. will this provide me with a nice low-noise amplified output?
2. The loop after the photodiode with R3 still confuses me. Is this just to pull V_Out low when no current is flowing?

Comment: For one thing, the + and - of your op amp are backwards.   Just swap them.

Comment: I realized. Will I be good then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The front page of the OP07 datasheet says it can run from +/- 3 V supplies, but all specs are for +/- 15 V. And you're only providing 5 V (with a resistor in the negative supply line, why?).
2. You have your op-amp connected for positive feedback, not negative.
3. Once you fix the feedback, your circuit will try to produce a negative output voltage proportional to the photocurrent of D7. But the op-amp has no negative supply voltage, so it won't be able to do this.

You need to go back to the drawing board and re-think your op-amp selection, how you power it, and how you make the feedback connection.

Various IC vendors (Analog, TI, etc) have app notes showing how to design an op-amp TIA circuit, so consider using a proven design from one of those.

Comment: So what you suggest, is turning the op-amp around, and use another amp like this: https://dk.farnell.com/microchip/mcp6041-e-p/ic-op-amp-1-4v-sngl-r-r-8dip/dp/1840866 ?

Comment: @JeppeChristensen, Fig 1 [here](http://www.tij.co.jp/jp/lit/an/snoa942a/snoa942a.pdf) shows a reasonable TIA configuration with a single supply. You might want to use your ADC's reference voltage as the input to the non-inverting pin rather than a resistor divider.

Comment: I see, but I need more knowledge in order to understand what's going on here. it's extremely intimidating, as I don't have a background in this.

Comment: https://my.vanderbilt.edu/imaginginstrumentation2016/2016/01/week-2-construction-of-photodiode-circuit-and-servo-motor-code-development/ could something like this work as well? - this, I somewhat understand.

Comment: @JeppeChristensen, yes but you need an op-amp with very good rail-to-rail input and output if you want to be able to measure small optical signals.

Comment: ah, i see ! so thats why we do it reverse biased usually? because the mA difference is easier to see detailed?